# How can I avoid this Interface Builder crash in Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I've made a demo video showing how I make Interface Builder in Xcode 4.4 crash:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRLGOmg9LpQ&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Currently I'm struggling to continue my work due to this problem.

How can I avoid this crash? Any ideas, work-arounds, manual xib files tweaks, etc?

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 0):

It's all ok for me following your youtube video, but i'm with 4.2 on Snow Leopard and my resulting object structure is slightly different.

[image]

was it ok with 4.2 and start to crash only with 4.4?

Comment: It was alright for me on 4.3, and only started to crash with 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Is it still happening, or have you fixed it?

Looking closely at your video, I think the error in the crash log is the same as the crashes I had earlier this week:

[Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)

Try switching off auto layout and seeing if it helps.

Once Interface Builder is working reliably, you seem to be able to switch auto layout back on again without re-creating the problem.

Comment: My problems were in 4.5 -- but I'm glad you've sorted it.