# Xcode Storyboard crash

Tags: xcode, crash, storyboard, corrupt

Whenever I add an object (specifically a UIButton or UILabel) to my Storyboard view, Xcode crashes. I've tried rebooting and reinstalling Xcode. I've also tried to recreate my view in a new project. It doesn't crash at first, but it does once I add a few more buttons to the Storyboard.

When I right click on MainStoryboard.storyboard in the Navigator and select "Open As: Property List", I get an error: "The data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted." In fact, this error appears when I try to open my .h and .m files in the same manner.

I'm running the newest version of Xcode (4.5) on Mountain Lion. Below is part of a crash log. Please let me know if I need to include more of it.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G182
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-1926/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:651
Details:  Failed to arbitrate IBNSLayoutConstraint, IBUIButton, IBUILabel, IBUIView, and IBUIViewController.
```

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: IBAssertionFailure
Exception reason: ASSERTION FAILURE: 
Reason:     All views needing candidate constraints have already had constraints generated. This most likely indicates a bug involving layout of the following views:
    Layout engine frame ({{169, 392}, {64, 43}}) of > does not match canvas frame ({{168, 392}, {64, 43}})

UPDATE:

Apparently I didn't research well enough. I found someone with the exact same problem:
[Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)

Right click on Storyboard in the navigator -> Show File Inspector -> Uncheck "Use Autolayout"

Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks for this post. I had same problem. I wasn't using a storyboard, but had same issue. Just had to uncheck "Use Autolayout" under Interface Builder Document.

Comment: I have the same issue, but unchecking "Use Autolayout" does not solve my issue. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)