# Xcode crashes when I open a specific XIB file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, xib

I had a `XIB` file which worked fine until today - when I try to open it in Xcode, the beachball appears and after 1 minute Xcode crashes. Others `XIBs` work just fine. Also, if I just build and run the project right to my device, its also work (and XIB works at the app).

Here is the error message:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G1004
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-1929/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:651
Details:  Failed to arbitrate IBNSLayoutConstraint, IBUIButton, IBUIImageView, IBUILabel, IBUITextField, and IBUIView.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

I will appreciate any ideas and thoughts!

Comment: Did you open that xib file in some different Xcode version recently? Especially in some developer preview of not yet released versions?

Comment: @HermannKlecker no, I did not. I have a Lion version right now and, unfortunaly, I am unable to set Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the autoLayout Property ? Uncheck the checkbox that says **Use AutoLayout** and it should work fine. Unchecking this and then saving the file seems to fix the problem for me earlier. check this link for further details  [Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)

Comment: I dont use autolayout + I cant make any changes in xib because when I open it - it crashes.

Comment: Did you check the link I added here, same is mentioned and solved there.

Answer (score 12):

If Xcode crashes as soon as you click on the xib file, you won't be able to uncheck **Use AutoLayout**. Here's how you can change it:

1. Right-click on the .xib file in the Project Navigator
2. Choose **Open As...** > **Source Code**
3. Find this line towards the end: `<bool key="IBDocument.UseAutolayout">YES</bool>`
4. Change `YES` to `NO`
5. Save File
6. Right-click on the .xib file again in the Project Navigator
7. Choose **Open As...** > **Interface Builder - iOS**

Comment: Darn. I was hoping that would work. I have filed 28497465 with bugreporter. The following is the header of my file (it's a little old) - `<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4510" systemVersion="12F37" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="NO">`

Comment: My workaround was to load the file into Xcode 7.3.1 and use it as a reference to attempt to rebuild it in 8.0.  (This invariably led to crashes likely caused by related issues.)