# XCODE keeps crashing. Deals with auto layout

Tags: uitableview, crash, osx-mountain-lion, autolayout, xcode5

I clicked to turn off auto layout.  And now I click the check box to turn it on, and xcode immediately crashes..Every time.  I'm pretty sure that all tableviews have a datasource.  I can't work on the project! Please help.

```
Process:         Xcode [5748]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0 (3332.25)
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 38302662
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [144]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-09-30 00:12:40.236 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F37)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          62599 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           13
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  4441 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   13


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-   3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:670
Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBUIDatePicker, IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUITableViewCellContentView.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Exception reason: UITableView dataSource is not set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced this problem and removing all of the *File Owner's* **Outlets** and **Referencing Outlets** did the trick.

**Note:** Firstly, as I couldn't turn off autoLayout graphically as Xcode crashed just by trying to view the *.xib*, I managed to do it following [AbuYusuph's suggestion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19520135/1200733)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting the **symlinks** I had from the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/ to the /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport. I hope this will help.

Comment: How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you created symbolic links on /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport or any other location? If yes, just delete the symlink file/folder and build again, if no, this solution wont work for you.

Comment: I didn't manually add any symlinks, not sure if it might do it automatically or something I did may have caused them?  In iOS DeviceSupport folder I have other folders like 5.0 and 5.1.1....  Would it be in there?  Why is this not a problem that a lot of other developers are having?

Answer (score 0):

I just remade an entire viewController and it works now. Not really answering the question. I am thinking it's just a glitch