# How to use iOS 10 simulators in Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode7.3, xcode8-beta6

I installed **Xcode 8 beta 6** version and copied DeveloperDiskImage to relevant folders. But Xcode 7 does not show iOS 10 devices. I tried using [Use Xcode 7 with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/how-use-xcode-7-with-ios-10) this article. 
I think Xcode 7 cannot run because of ***Xcode 8 beta 6*** version. Have you anyone tried iOS 10 (***Xcode 8 beta 6***) simulators with xcode 7?
 I tried whole day. but still could not find a correct answer.

Comment: I would appreciate the advice as well