# Can we install iOS 10 Simulator on Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios10

I want to test my app on iOS 10 simulator. But I don't want to build the project using Xcode 8 yet. So, can i install iOS 10 simulator in to Xcode 7.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just checking the apple developer forum

Below is the details

```
Xcode 7.3

Xcode 7.3 requires a Mac running OS X version 10.11 or later. It includes updated support for iOS 9.3, watchOS 2.2, OS X version 10.11.4, and tvOS 9.2 as well as many feature improvements.
```

Check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_7_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015242-SW1

Comment: Not sure we can install the iOS 10 simulator, but we can run on the iOS 10 device from Xcode 7.3 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/how-use-xcode-7-with-ios-10

Comment: Yes, you asked for installation. It won't be possible. Device can be configured and managed with Xcode 7.3 with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/how-use-xcode-7-with-ios-10

Comment: this link is dead which is why its best to put the answer "here"