# Deployment target 6.0 on Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

The lowest deployment target on Xcode 8.0 is 8.0 (If I choose from the list). If I try to change it manually I get a warning:

```
Applications using launch screen files and targeting iOS 7.1 and earlier need to also include a launch image in an asset catalog.
```

I have a launch images in assets.xcassets.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Just do exactly what it said, go to asset.xcassets and add a launch image, since before ios 7 they dont use launch screen xib

Comment: In Xcode 8.0 Only Supported deployment targets iOS 8.0 or later.

Comment: is not possbile then go for xcode 7.x version

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Xcode 7.x versions will work with iOS 10?

Comment: How to run iOS 10 on Xcode 7 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/use-xcode-7-with-ios-10