# Compatibility for Xcode 7, iOS 8, MacSierra and old iOS 6 and 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-sierra

I am currently on EL Capitan. I wish to clear few doubts before deciding to upgrade to Sierra.

1. Can Xcode 7 run on Sierra?
2. Can iOS simulator run on Sierra ?
3. Can Xcode 7 in Sierra build and test with iOS 6 and iOS 7 actual devices? As my app is still supporting them. As i know, Xcode 8 can no longer build and run on ios 6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes xcode 7 will work on Sierra, and all simulators will work. **But the problem is that you cannot run real devices with version 10.0 or greater. Also you cannot upload a build to Appstore using sierra+xcode 7**. For that u need xcode 8.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If i use xcode to build release , is it still compatible with ios6 and iso7?

Comment: u cannot release any build to appstore when u r in xcode 7 and seirra.. Seirra doesnot allow it, You must be in xcode 8.

Comment: Yes but i need to make sure that it can run in ios6  with xcode 8 build ?

Comment: You cannot run xcode 8 build on iOS6. Please check this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610174/deployment-target-6-0-on-xcode-8-0

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can confirm that I am able to work on xcode 7, then build and release in code 8. It is still compatible with iOS 6.