# Is it possible to use new classes of iOS 10 with Xcode7?

Tags: ios, xcode7, ios10, xcode8, usernotifications

## What I want

I would like to use new iOS10 classes and methods with Xcode 7.
Is it possible and if yes, how?

## What I tried (it didn't work)

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945377/1670830), I have tried to do

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0 (14A345)" "/Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0"
```

but it didn't work. I am able to run code on a device running iOS10 but I want to use new classes and methods (`@import UserNotifications;` for instance).

Comment: This is not posible.

Comment: @BharatNakum are you sure? why?

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is to support running on devices with iOS 10.

To support new functions you need to include headers and link with libraries from new SDK (you can try to copy it too).

Comment: Yep, but that's my question: how to do it?

Comment: Look into Xcode.app subdirectories of installed Xcode 8