# Use Xcode 7.3.1 with iOS 10.1 (14B67) device

Tags: ios, xcode, build, sdk

I'm using `Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)`. I want to install my app on an iPhone 7 plus with `iOS 10 (14B67)`.

I have the `10.0 (14A345)` folder from Xcode 8 in `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`.

I used this code `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.1\ \(14B67\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` in Terminal to create an alias named `10.1 (14B67)`.

The DeviceSupport-folder looks like this:
[image: DeviceSupport-folder]

But I'm still getting `Could not find Developer Disk Image` when trying to build on my iPhone device.

What can I do?

**UPDATE**

The only solution seems to have the original 10.1 (14B65) folder. You can download the folder for 10.1 (14B65) here: http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/10114b65

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It's not appropriate to post some offsite link to some unknown file for others to download.

Comment: Why shouldn't I do that?

Comment: Stack overflow is for asking questions, not making files available for others.

Comment: But I think it can be very helpful for others. It's senseless to download the 8 GB just to extract the 10 MB folder.

Comment: David, if you think you have found a solution which is useful for others, you should not embed it in the question. The question section is for questions only. You should post the solution in the answer section. You may also accept your own answer if you like. Thanks.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/use-xcode-7-with-ios-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 10.1 requires Xcode 8.1. So you need to get 8.1 installed then you can add the soft link.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But, is there no online source when I can get these folders?