# Xcode 7.3.1, Unable to run the app on IOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode7

Unable to run MobileFirst cordova app on device from Xcode

Application is running on simulator successfully

I have added supported DeveloperDiskImage for testing device in Xcode

Getting the error

> header 'stdatomic.h' not found

Version specs:

- node: 8.7.0
- npm: 5.5.1
- cordova: 6.5.0
- Xcode: 7.3.1

**Here is my error.**

[image]

Comment: Did you generate SDK in device target?

Comment: I have referred this link for adding device support

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/use-xcode-7-with-ios-10

Comment: You mentioned running on simulator. What version of iOS did the simulator image run?

Comment: simulator image ran on version 10.0