# Unable to open .xib file

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I am trying to run one of my old project. But getting following error

Command

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Also, I can access one of my `.xib` file. That is, whenever I try to open that particular `.xib` file `Xcode` closed.

How could I fix this error?

Comment: @AnikerShah >> Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not yet. Temporarily I had just created another .xib.

Comment: more responses at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670585/xcode-crashes-when-i-open-a-specific-xib-file

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this type of weird problem happens with xCode. Basic step would be:

1. Clean the project.
2. restart your xCode and Simulator.
3. reboot your computer.

For more see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422033/why-am-i-getting-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-255) and [apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3178402?start=0&tstart=0).

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Also sometimes resetting the simulator also helps in such situations: **iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings**

Answer (score 0):

Select interface builder 
[image]

then in document interface document choose compactable xcode version

[image]