# Xcode 5 crashes when I enable use auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

By error I disabled use auto layout in my storyboard and when I want to re enable it again the Xcode crashes. I need help please! It's very important....

The error is:

```
Process:         Xcode [315]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [133]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-01-27 08:33:35.371 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          2942 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  2564 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   12
Anonymous UUID:                      24878C32-E46C-C700-0F6F-8B0D08B0549F

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending userDidChangeValue: to <IDEInspectorBooleanProperty: 0x7fec6f13dcd0> from <NSButton: 0x7fec6f09da40>
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3747/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:670
Details:  Failed to run one shot request for IBUIDatePicker, IBUIImageView, IBUITabBar, IBUITabBarItem, IBUITableView, IBUIView, IBUIViewController, and IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Exception reason: UITableView dataSource is not set
```

The error is larger, but I can't add much code.

**EDIT:**

An image to my Xcode:

[image: Xcode screenshoot]

**EDIT:**
I re-installed Xcode again, but the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstall your Xcode?

Comment: I suggest that you file a bug report @Apple. Xcode should not crash. Did it work when you re-installed Xcode?

Comment: add your all delegates properly

Comment: I re-install it now, It crashes again... :'(

Comment: @iDev can you explain me more about your comment?

Comment: is it possible to open your code in another device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Finally I solved it taking an old version of my storyboard and coping (cmd+c) the new viewcontrollers, and when I copy to the old storyboard this viewcontroller have "use auto layout" enabled. It's a bad solution (but faster). In my opinion this problem is an important Xcode bug.

Answer (score 0):

Check your UITableView dataSource and delegate connection in Storybord

[image]

Comment: See my edit. I was working with autolayout, by I disabled it by error, and I can't re enable it again.

Comment: It is **not** the application OP is writing what crashes. It is Xcode itself. (Yes, this is one of the rare questions where the Xcode tag is **actually** appropriate.)

Comment: @H2CO3 What do you suggest?

Comment: I have a lot of tableviews, a lot. I think is a Xcode problem. I need resolved it beucause I can't do anything more in my ptoject.

Comment: @Retro I'd suggest submitting a radar about it. Maybe opening Xcode itself in a debugger and trying to find some debugging symbols (honestly, that's quite unlikely).

Comment: @kova Did you try to disconnect your connection of UITableViewControlelr and then enable the autolayout?

Comment: I disconnect all dataSource and delegates of TableViewController and it crashes again. buttons and labels connections can cause it too?

Comment: Yes, its saying Failed to run one shot request for IBUIDatePicker, IBUIImageView, IBUITabBar, IBUITabBarItem, IBUITableView, IBUIView, IBUIViewController, and IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide.

Answer (score 0):

try link help you more

[Xcode Interface Builder crashes when I edit storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580881/xcode-interface-builder-crashes-when-i-edit-storyboard)

Start by trying to narrow down the problem. First, create a new iOS application project and see if selecting the xib file from the project navigator crashes Xcode. If Xcode doesn't crash, that is evidence there was something wrong with the xib file.

If Xcode crashes when selecting a xib file on a new iOS project, try adding an application xib file to the project by choosing File > New > New File. The application xib file is in the User Interface section of the new file assistant. Select the newly created xib file to see whether or not it crashes. If Xcode doesn't crash, that is evidence there is something wrong with the xib file that is part of Apple's Xcode project templates.

If Xcode crashes when adding a xib file to your project, create a Mac Cocoa application project. Select the xib file to see if it crashes Xcode. If Xcode doesn't crash, that is evidence that something is wrong with your iOS SDK installation.

If Xcode is still crashing, quit Xcode, trash Xcode's preferences file, and restart Xcode. The Xcode preferences file is located in the following directory:

/Users/YourUsername/Library/Preferences

If trashing the preferences file doesn't stop the crashing, reinstall Xcode.